# springboot with GCP BigTable

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, bigtable

i am a new bee to GCP and trying to develop springboot rest api that connects to GCP Bigtable, do we have a quickstart guide that helps in development.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, there is. Check out this link to get started. You need the Java client library.

https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java

for Maven:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
      <version>26.1.4</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-bigtable</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

Then check this for usage:
https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-java

```
import com.google.api.gax.rpc.NotFoundException;
import com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.BigtableDataClient;
import com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.BigtableDataSettings;
import com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.models.Row;
import com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.models.RowCell;

public class Quickstart {

  public static void main(String... args) {
    String projectId = args[0]; // my-gcp-project-id
    String instanceId = args[1]; // my-bigtable-instance-id
    String tableId = args[2]; // my-bigtable-table-id

    quickstart(projectId, instanceId, tableId);
  }

  public static void quickstart(String projectId, String instanceId, String tableId) {
    BigtableDataSettings settings =
        BigtableDataSettings.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).setInstanceId(instanceId).build();

    // Initialize client that will be used to send requests. This client only needs to be created
    // once, and can be reused for multiple requests. After completing all of your requests, call
    // the "close" method on the client to safely clean up any remaining background resources.
    try (BigtableDataClient dataClient = BigtableDataClient.create(settings)) {
      System.out.println("\nReading a single row by row key");
      Row row = dataClient.readRow(tableId, "r1");
      System.out.println("Row: " + row.getKey().toStringUtf8());
      for (RowCell cell : row.getCells()) {
        System.out.printf(
            "Family: %s    Qualifier: %s    Value: %s%n",
            cell.getFamily(), cell.getQualifier().toStringUtf8(), cell.getValue().toStringUtf8());
      }
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
      System.err.println("Failed to read from a non-existent table: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Error during quickstart: \n" + e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```